# вывести по 20 записей из БД на каждой странице

Tags: mysql, sql

Вечер добрый,

К примеру юзер заходит на первую страницу, и из таблицы получает 20 записей переходит на вторую страницу и получает следующие 20 записей. и.т.д
Делать на каждой странице?

LIMIT  0, 20
LIMIT  20, 40
LIMIT  40, 60

Вопрос: Как это проще и обычно реализовывают.

Comment: Делайте, в чём проблема?

Comment: Чувство что это далеко не самый лучший вариант, и есть альтернатива.

Comment: Чем вас этот вариант не устроил?

Comment: Значения LIMIT задаете в виде переменных, которые умножаете на номер текущей страницы... Так все и делают!

Comment: Да вариант конечно не самый лучший. И да, так делают многие, просто из за простоты способа. И оно нормально работает когда у вас пара тысяч записей. Если больше, то большие смещения в limit начинают тормозить, потому что MySQL вынужден прочитать все записи с начала и выбросить те, что пропускаем. Как вариант - запоминать значение ключа сортировки в последней записи на странице и следующую брать `where key > x`. так оно гораздо быстрее работает, но возни конечно больше что бы это сделать

Comment: @Mike и теряется возможность перейти на произвольную страницу, а не на предыдущую/следующую

Comment: @andreymal Переход на произвольную страницу вообще зло. Вот реально, если дано много страниц для перехода то люди вынуждены тыкать на случайные страницы, что бы понять есть там то, что им надо или нет. Уж лучше вывести алфавит или указатель дат. Кроме того в дизайне сейчас чаще преобладает живая подгрузка по мере прокрутки, вот она как раз всегда дает "следующую".

Comment: @Mike вот злом является **особенно** живая подгрузка, которая бесит вообще всех адекватных людей

Comment: @andreymal Ну значит я неадекватный, мне нравится живая прокрутка. Конечно при условии, что записей не больше тысячи. Я за более точный поиск что бы страницы были вообще не нужны. Потому что более 1000 записей все равно никто читать не будет

Comment: @Mike а указатель алфавита или дат применим не всегда, например когда на один день или на одну букву присутствуют тысячи записей, или если сортировка идёт по какому-нибудь невнятному показателю типа релевантности в поиске или среднему рейтингу чего-нибудь

Comment: @Mike а живая прокрутка прекрасно совместима с любым механизмом пагинации, главное — не выпиливать саму пагинацию, как это обычно любят делать (хороший пример — обсуждения ВК)